# Что есть сказуемое в придаточном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

Она не допускала мысли, *что счастливое будущее возможно для нее с кем-то другим*.

Answer (score 5):

Составное именное сказуемое "возможно", глагол-связка "быть" в форме настоящего времени пропущен, именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным.

Comment: Vera, большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вы сейчас что-то путаете. Термина *сказуемое в придаточном предложении* нет, есть сказуемое. Сказуемое — это один из главных членом предложения, который отвечает на ряд вопросов: что происходит с субъектом (подлежащим)? каково подлежащее? и пр. Если вас что-то конкретное интересует — оформляйте вопросы корректно.

Что касается сказуемого в том предложении, которое вы выделили, то им будет: (было, будет) возможно. Это составное именное сказуемое (их ещё СИС называют), стоящее в настоящем времени.

Comment: простите, я хотела сказать "глагол"! я не могла наити глагол... уфф, как стыдно!!!

Comment: Если речь идет о глаголе, то его в придаточном предложении нет. Есть только глагол-связка, но она нулевая.